# Dafny: the method must provide an equal or more permissive precondition than in its parent trait

Tags: dafny

Currently, I'm trying to build a trait for a BinaryTree in Dafny.
The following error occurs for the implementation of the Insert method in the class:

> the method must provide an equal or more permissive precondition than
>   in its parent trait

Why does this error occur, even if the same preconditions exist for the method in the trait and in the class?

This is the trait:

```
trait DataStorage {
    ghost var Contents: set<int>
    ghost var Repr: set<object>

    method Insert(val: int)
        modifies this, Repr
        requires Valid()
        ensures Valid() && fresh(Repr - old(Repr))
        ensures Contents == old(Contents) + {val}

    predicate Valid()
        reads this, Repr

    (...)
}
```

An this is the corresponding implementation

```
class BinaryTree extends DataStorage {

    var root: Node?;

    predicate Valid()
        reads this, Repr
    {
        this in Repr &&
        (root == null ==> Contents == {}) &&
        (root != null ==>
        root in Repr && root.Repr <= Repr && this !in root.Repr &&
        root.Valid() &&
        Contents == root.Contents)
    }


    method Insert(val: int)
        requires Valid()
        modifies Repr
        ensures Valid() && fresh(Repr - old(Repr))
        ensures Contents == old(Contents) + {val}
    {
        var n := insert_helper(root, val);
        root := n;
        Contents := root.Contents;
        Repr := root.Repr + {this};
    }

    (...)
}
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error (even after guessing a definition for `Node`).

Comment: Last week, there were two major feature additions to Dafny regarding traits. Traits and the classes that extend them can now have type parameters, and traits can extend other traits. A number of bugs were also fixed along the way. If you're working with traits, I suggest you sync up to the latest Dafny sources.